# How to get an easier way of generating the alphabet in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, project, shortcut, alphabet

i am trying to make a project,to experiment and learn C++, i didnt finish making it,but what it does is you type in a 3 or 4 (the variable noc) word and the program runs through all the possible (noc) letter words or nonsense, until it finds yours,so there are 2 factors: the length of the word or nonsense and what characters it can type,in my case i just want the alphabet
so here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
using namespace std;

const int noc = 3;

int main() {

    string used[noc];
    string inp;
    cin >> inp;
    char albet[] = {'a','b','c'};
    cout << "Starting..." << endl;
    usleep(1);
    string aiput = "";
    while(aiput != inp){
        for(int i = 0; i <= noc; i++){
            aiput = aiput +
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

currently i need the alphabet in the array called 'albet' (i come up with short words for what they mean its easy to forget tho)
so please can you get me a way to generate the alphabet in C++ quickly instead of having to type all of them one by one

Comment: `'a'`-`'z'` is contiguous in ASCII, but no guaranty in C++ (in EBCDIC, that range is not contiguous). I don't think you can generate it so with arithmetic in portable way.

Comment: @Jarod42 Since OP is still learning there should be no problem relying on only ASCII.

Comment: True, and the questioner may go through their entire programming career without seeing a non-contiguous or insanely ordered character set, but it's good to know they exist.

Comment: Why not just type in 26 letters as a string and use that string?  English isn't a language that has thousands of characters.  Sometimes the simplest solutions aren't so obvious.  Even if you had to type all of them one-by-one, so what?  That is 26 characters, 52, quotes, and commas.  That is hardly any work, IMO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because all characters can be represented in ASCII codes ('a' starts at 97, all ASCII codes are int), you can simply make a loop to do that. For example:

```
char albet[26];

for (int ch = 'a'; ch <= 'z'; ch++) {
    //do ch-'a' because we start at index 0
    albet[ch-'a'] = ch;
}
```

and you are done!

Answer (score 9):

When you need a character array you do not have to use individual character literals one by one, as in

```
char albet[] = {'a','b','c','d','e','f',... uff this is tedious ...};
```

You can use a string literal instead:

```
const std::string albet{"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"};
```

Took me ~10 seconds to type and compared to other answers, this does not rely on ASCII encoding (which is not guaranteed).

Comment: I upvoted this.  My comments in the main section describe what you've done.  It's amazing that sometimes the simplest solutions just get overlooked.

Answer (score 6):

You could use [`std::iota`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota), which is a great algorithm for this use case:

```
char albet[26] {};
std::iota(std::begin(albet), std::end(albet), 'a');
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/59EN87).

Note that this is not *guaranteed* to work in c++, unless you have ASCII encoding, but if you can rely on that you'll be fine.

Comment: I think it would be neat if the standard library had a compile-time constant to check if string literal encoding is ASCII, or at least if alphabet is consecutive. There is [already one for checking that floating point types us iec559](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/is_iec559) and it feels like the use case for that is narrower than checking that letters are contiguous.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux That would be nice. I wonder what the applicability of this is, i.e. are there many architectures that use non-ascii encoding? If not, I expect eventually the standard to mandate this, like they've done for non 2'scomplement architectures.

Answer (score 1):

Each letter has an ASCII representation. More about that [here](http://www.asciitable.com/).

They are processed as numbers, being cast, and transformed into characters. For example, the letter `a` would be represented by the number 97 in decimal.

```
int aInAscii = 97;
printf("%c", (char)aInAscii);
```

The upper code would print, as you expect, the letter `a`. Why? Because we have just converted the number 97 to it's ASCII corresponding character.

So, in this way, we could generate the alphabet, using only numbers. A short example would be here (I preferred casting it before so that the starting and ending points are more clear.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<char> alphabet;
    int aLetterCode = (int)'a'; // ASCII code for letter a (97)
    int zLetterCode = (int)'z'; // ASCII code for letter z (122)
    for (int charAsciiCode = aLetterCode; charAsciiCode <= zLetterCode; charAsciiCode++) {
        alphabet.push_back((char)charAsciiCode);
    }
    for (char c : alphabet) {
        cout << c << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It would be preferred to use `cout` instead of `printf` for your first example.

Comment: @SealsRock12 couldn't agree more with that, but I wanted to use the formatting specifier to make it obvious that it is a character ("%c").

Comment: I see. That's fine.

Answer (score 1):

You just can also make a function that returns a char, without generating an array, like this:

```
char get_alphabet_letter(unsigned int index, bool is_upper = false)
{
    char letter = 97 + index;
    if(is_upper) return letter - 32;
    return letter;  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

from the given below code, you can generate uppercase alphabets of English. Uppercase alphabhets starts in ASCII from A = 65 to Z = 90. And, then, typecast the
integral value of uppercase alphabets into character using char().

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main () {
    char a[26];
for (int i=65 ; i<91 ; i++) {
     int a[65-i] = char(i);
     cout<<a<<endl;

return 0;
}
```